# keytool import certificate and java system property

Tags: java, ssl

I have to call a WebService via https. If I import the crt file in a specific keystore and then I set System properties:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", path);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", pwd)
```

Everithing works fine.
If I try to import crt file as a trusted certificate with this instruction:

```
keytool -trustcacerts -import -alias <alias> -file <path to crt file>
```

I get an javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException.

How can I avoid the use of System properties?

Comment: Define 'import the crt file in a specific keystore', and explain how it is different from the second step.

Comment: First operation import:
keytool -import -keystore mykeystore ...
And then set "mykeystore" as "java.net.ssl.truStstore" property.

In the second operation I use the "trustcacerts" option in keytool. I thought it was enough to access to web service without the setting of system properties

Comment: No it isn't, but you haven't answered my question. You seem to expect Java to magically know which KeyStore you imported it into, and its password. It doesn't.

Comment: Ehm, not magically. I thought "-trustcacerts" was enough. It isn't.

Comment: It is enough to tell *that invocation of the keytool* to import the specified certificate(s) as trusted in the keystore you specified *to that invocation of the keystore.* Period. Some other JVM running at some other time doesn't know (a) the keystore (b) the invocation flags (c) the certificate source and incidentially (d) the truststore password. No magic.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I avoid the use of System properties?

Use a CA-signed certificate.

Comment: What do you mean? It's not my certifcate. I can't edit it